# Java Hashtable .containsKey(String key) is returning true even when the strings and hashcodes are different... How?

Tags: java, string, key, hashtable, hashcode

I'm currently having some issues with my Hashtable in java, where FEightPuzzle is a class which I've created.

Inside my class I have a String which is storing the key for each instance. Now during my program when I check inside the Hashtable for duplicate instances I sometimes "find" some when really the found ones are different.

Take for example when I call bol.containsKey(current.key) where bol is a HT and current is an FEightPuzzle.

When this is true I check the values of the keys and they are

```
current.key =
"8 14 11 0 6 12 13 1 10 4 5 9 15 2 3 7"

bol.get(current.key).key =
"12 8 4 0 13 9 5 1 14 10 6 2 15 11 7 3"
```

with values

```
current.key.hashCode() = -950607924

bol.get(current.key).key.hashCode() = -1856769042
```

I'm sorry to bother you but this problem is really getting to me, and it was the last thing I expected tonight to be honest (don't you love that)... Any hints or answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As a side note, `Hashtable` is obsolete, better use a `HashMap` (or `ConcurrentHashMap` if you need thread safety).

Comment: Is it possible that you are changing keys of items already added to your map (without removing and re-adding them to keep map integrity intact)?

Comment: Good question, but no I don't think it's possible. An instance's state is set when it's initialised, no changes are made from then - and that's where the key is made

Comment: Can you post the code where you are adding the objects to the HT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reread your question, and as I understand it you have the following problem:

You do

```
bol.containsKey(current.key)
```

to check if `current` is already in `bol`.

When it returns true, you expect that the value mapped to by `current.key` should indeed be `current`, but as your hash-codes indicate, it's not.

The problem is likely to be one of the following:

1. You didn't put the puzzle object in the hashtable correctly in the first place.

   You should do

   ```
   bol.put(somePuzzle.key, somePuzzle)
   ```
2. You changed the key when the puzzle was in the map. THIS IS NOT ALLOWED.

   **After you've added the entry in the map, you may not change the key without removing / reinserting the mapping.**

   The Hashtable will look for the object, based on the key you provided when inserting.
3. You've accidentally provided the *same key* for multiple different puzzle objects (in which case, one `put` will override a previous one)

---

One suggestion would be to let FEightPuzzle override hashCode and equals and use a HashSet instead of a Hashtable.

Comment: also I mistyped that before, it's fixed now, those were the values from the actual keys. the FEightPuzzle toString method is quite different to that.

Comment: Kind of, I gazed over it, they say that the java HT uses a key, but for identical keys the extra objects are bucketed, kind of like where one key can point to many objects using either an array or linked list. The thing is that this makes no sense with what is described in the java HT api, as they make it clear that each key should uniquely map to a single object. The only reason I discovered this was happening was when I exported my lists and tried to reenter them all into a HT, the HT only half filled up as it (I assume) was overwriting old objects that had the same key...

Comment: Oh my goodness, it appears that one of the first values I put into the HT uses the wrong key. THANKYOU so much for pointing that out... over 200,000 objects in the HT and it was just the very first one which was giving me my error. Thank you, what a relief.

Comment: @Sekm: No, the Hashtable does not allow multiple values for the same key. The bucketing with linked list is only used for different keys with the same hash code (or different hash codes which by chance map to the same bucket).

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann That makes things a lot clearer, thankyou for that explanation - I was wondering what would happen in those cases (seeing as hashcodes seem to be stored as integers), I take it that in those cases the equals method will be used to obtain 100% accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you're misunderstanding what `Hashtable` does. It maps keys to values. So calling `get(key)` on your key is going to return the value you provided with `put(key, value)`. Now if you're always putting the same value in as the key you should expect the same thing, however in that case all you need is a `HashSet`. If you're putting the same values in for different keys, it is going to allow that. Only the keys are unique in a `Hashtable` (and `HashMap` is the same).

Comment: Nono I understand that, I just mistyped it when I first posted the question, I'm sorry that was my mistake

Comment: Ah I see. So it looks like you're storing the key as a member of the value object? Are you perhaps reusing those value objects and setting the key for the same instance as used by another key? If you can include some code snippets it'll probably be helpful for people here to assist.