# HashTable getcontainsKey does not work

Tags: java, hashtable, containskey

I don't understand why this simple method does not work

My class `AccessChecker` has the  attribute `Hashtable<String, List<Permission>> permissions = new Hashtable<String, List<Permission>>();` with two methods:

**First method**

If I put `this.permissions.containsKey(key)` at the end of this method , with a good key, it works.

```
public void updatePermissions() {
    List<Permission> permissionsTmp = permissionRepository.findAllWithEagerRelationships();

    // clear permissions
    this.permissions = new Hashtable<>();

    // load all permissions
    for (Permission permission : permissionsTmp) {
        Profil profil = profilRepository.findOne(permission.getProfil().getId());
        permission.setProfil(profil);
        UserFonc user = userFoncRepository.findOne(permission.getUserFonc().getId());
        permission.setUserFonc(user);

        log.error("updatePermissions ** user login = " + user.getNom());

        for (WebService webService: profil.getWebServices()) {
            String key = createKeyPermissions(user.getNom().toLowerCase(), webService.getNom(), webService.getMethode());
            log.error("updatePermissions ** key = " + key);
            if (this.permissions.containsKey(key)){
                this.permissions.get(key).add(permission);
            }
            else {
                List<Permission> newPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
                newPermissions.add(permission);
                this.permissions.put(key, newPermissions);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Second method**

But, when I do this in method `hasAccessToWebservice()`, it does NOT work for the same key...

```
public boolean hasAccessToWebservice(HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean hasAccess = false;

    String webservice = getServiceFromRequest(request);
    String methode = request.getMethod();
    String login = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin();
    String userAgent = request.getHeader(Constants.USER_AGENT);

    final String userLogin = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin();
    log.error("hasAccessToWebservice ** user login = " + userLogin);

    String key = createKeyPermissions(login.toLowerCase(), webservice, methode);
    log.error("hasAccessToWebservice ** key = " + key);

    log.error("hasAccessToWebservice ** element = " + this.permissions.size());

    Set t = this.permissions.keySet();
    log.error(t.toString());

    if (this.permissions.containsKey(key)) {
        log.error("hasAccessToWebservice ** key found !!");
        hasAccess = true;
    }
    return hasAccess;
}
```

Can you explain why?

Thank you

Comment: What does not work? Do you have an error or only you expected to have `containsKey(...) == true` and it's false?

Comment: containsKey return always false but when I do toString on my HashTable, I see my key

Comment: Would you mind giving an example with data as it makes me think of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5632315/4906586)? The link is also mentioning that `Hashtable` is obsolete and if you could, to switch to `HashMap`. Unrelated to problem but I see that you log everything in `log.error` but it looks like more `info` or `debug`

Comment: I replace Hashtable by HashMap but same result. In my log, I see waht I search keey "adminvannesSetBonSAVPOST" and my HashMap contains this key (HashMap.keySet().toString())  : [admin lorientSetBonSavPOST, adminvannesGetBonSavGET, admin lorientDeleteBonSavDELETE, adminvannesSetBonSavPOST, swaroskyGetBonSavGET, admin lorientGetBonSavGET,
adminvannesDeleteBonSavDELETE]

Comment: Changing to `HashMap` would magically resolve your problem, it was rather for the sake of being up to date. Is it normal to have `adminvannesSetBonSAVPOST` with `SAV` and `admanvannesSetBonSavPOST` with `Sav`? [String.equals() is case sensitive](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml)

Comment: Unrelated: is it expected to have the space in key for `Lorient` but not for `Vannes`? I don't know your system so I can't raise the `data inconsistency` flag but just letting you know

Comment: I remove space in key value but it does not works !!. I'm working on Windows 10, java 1.8 and framework jhipster

Comment: And how about the case sensitivity?

Comment: euh.. I don't know. How can I do this?

Comment: I put key on lowercase and it works !!! Thank you :)

Comment: I have posted an answer for summarizing your issue and to give you some food for thought if you're interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem summary

To summarise the topic, the problem revolved around the key consistency:

1. `Map.containsKey(Object key)` will basically check if `key` is among the `Map.keySet()` mainly by relying on `Object.hashCode()`
2. Your map key class is `String`. If you look at [`String.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) code, you'll see that it relies on each single character value.

   > Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object is computed as
   >
   > `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`
   >
   > using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

   Value can be found in the [ASCII Table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) highlighting that **`hashCode()` is case-sensitive**

### Solution / Improvement

- The easiest solution is to ensure that `createKeyPermissions` method always produces consistent key by for interface putting everything in lowercase
- Use a [`TreeMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22336599/4906586) with a comparator where the most fitted one is [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call updatePermissions to put all the data into your permissions before running hasAccessToWebservice

If you run hasAccessToWebservice without updatePermissions, you don't have anything in the permissions list => this.permissions.containsKey(key) not work

Comment: updatePermissions is call on launch application and contains data.